# zsh: standard error not getting redirected

Tags: zsh

I have created an empty director for testing

```
$ mkdir test

$ cd test

$ grep da *
zsh: no matches found: *
```

Now i am trying to redirect the error `zsh: no matches found: *` to a file. (my purpose is only for testing and understanding, kindly dont ask what and why i want to do this)

```
$ grep da * 2> grep-errors.txt
zsh: no matches found: *
```

Now the error is still visible

```
$ ls -al   
total 60
drwxr-xr-x   2 test users  4096 Mar  2 20:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 117 test users 53248 Mar  2 20:25 ..
```

the file `grep-errors.txt` is not created

So what is happening here can some one explain. why the errors are not getting redirected to the file.

Comment: Because you're redirecting the error output from `grep`, but `grep` doesn't even run. The error message is from your shell, which at this point is still trying (and failing) to construct a command line.

Comment: Also, that error clearly says you're using zsh, not bash.

Comment: sorry zsh is the shell i am using.

Answer (score 2):

The redirection only applies to `grep`, but it is `zsh` itself producing that error when `*` doesn't expand to any matching files, *before* `grep` ever runs, or even before `zsh` tries to process the redirection.

One workaround is to disable the `NOMATCH` option, so that `*` is passed literally to `grep`. Then `grep` will run and produce an error (`grep: *: No such file or directory`) which will be written to the file.

```
% setopt NO_NOMATCH
% grep da * 2> grep-errors.txt
% cat grep-errors.txt
grep: *: No such file or directory
```

Comment: So is there any way to redirect the zsh or bash errors

Comment: Yes, but you are better off fixing the problem than logging the errors. Let the *caller* of your script redirect the shell's standard error if they don't want to see them (or if they want to save them).